# Optimizer is too large for GPU

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, gpu

I'm building a nn consisting of 2 hidden FC layers, where the weights are tensors [19000,19000] (I cannot make them smaller).

When I run everything of the network on CPU and only the optimizer (adagrad) on GPU, I'm fine (the allocated memory is 8990B). Since I need the weights to be clipped as well, I apply the function tf.clip_by_value() on the weigths (not the biases) in both layers. As of now, the allocated memory exceeds the 12GB of dedicated memory of the GPU.

Is there a way that I can split the optimizer over multiple GPU's or the cpu and GPU?

Comment: Why can't you use smaller weights? This is crazily big...

Comment: And what do you mean by "everything of the network on CPU and only optimizer on GPU"? If you mean forward pass on CPU and backprop on GPU, then you are wasting computing power because the weights would still be used on GPU, and so, you can do your forward pass on GPU too... 

And also, by default TF allocate all the gpu memory, so 8990 is not really what it uses but what it allocated. (If you did not specified an other behavior).

Their are methods to split the optimization, but for your case I don't think this is necessary because it looks like you still can improve over 1 GPU.